# Parse error with php, syntax error, unexpected '$aircrafttype' (T_VARIABLE)

Tags: php

I am getting a parse error with the following code. I have searched but could not find an answer.

error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$aircrafttype' (T_VARIABLE) in dbinput.php on line 58
```

Here is the code:

```
<?php


  if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    $data_missing = array();

    if(empty($_POST['airline'])) {
      $data_missing[] = 'Flygbolag';
    } else {
      $airline = $_POST['airline'];
    }

    if(empty($_POST['registration'])) {
      $data_missing[] = 'Registrering';
    } else {
      $registration = $_POST['registration'];
    }

    if(empty($_POST['msn'])) {
      $data_missing[] = 'MSN';
    } else {
      $msn = $_POST['msn'];
    }

    if(empty($_POST['aircrafttype'])) {
      $data_missing[] = 'Flygplanstyp';
    } else {
      $aircrafttype = $_POST['aircrafttype'];
    }

    if(empty($_POST['enginedata'])) {
      $data_missing[] = 'Motorer';
    } else {
      $enginedata = $_POST['enginedata'];
    }

    if(empty($_POST['loc'])) {
      $data_missing[] = 'Plats';
    } else {
      $loc = $_POST['loc'];
    }
  }

  if (empty($data_missing)) {
    require_once('../dbconnect.php');

    $query = "INSERT INTO Aircraft_spotted VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";

    $stmt = mysqli_prepare($conn, $query);
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ssisss", $airline, $registration, $msn, $aircrafttype, $enginedata, $loc);

    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

    $affected_rows = mysqli_stmt_affected_rows($stmt);

    if ($affected_rows == 1) {
      echo "Aircraft entered to database";
      mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
      mysqli_close($conn);
    } else {
      echo "Error occured: " . mysqli_error();
    }

  } else {
    echo "You need to enter the following data: <br />";

    foreach ($data_missing as $missing) {
      echo "$missing<br />";

      echo "string";
    }
  }

?>
```

I am grateful for any answer or help with the issue. Thanks a lot! Very much appreciate it!

Samuel

Answer (score 0):

check if your `$_POST['aircrafttype']` exists by `print_r($_POST)`

Probably you don't have set this or `aircrafttype` field is not sent to the POST. Try with:

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    $data_missing = array();

    if(empty($_POST['airline']) || !isset($_POST['airline'])) {
      $data_missing[] = 'Flygbolag';
    } else {
      $airline = $_POST['airline'];
    }

    if(empty($_POST['registration']) || !isset($_POST['registration'])) {
      $data_missing[] = 'Registrering';
    } else {
      $registration = $_POST['registration'];
    }

    if(empty($_POST['msn']) || !isset($_POST['msn'])) {
      $data_missing[] = 'MSN';
    } else {
      $msn = $_POST['msn'];
    }

    if(empty($_POST['aircrafttype']) || !isset($_POST['aircrafttype'])) {
      $data_missing[] = 'Flygplanstyp';
    } else {
      $aircrafttype = $_POST['aircrafttype'];
    }

    if(empty($_POST['enginedata']) || !isset($_POST['enginedata'])) {
      $data_missing[] = 'Motorer';
    } else {
      $enginedata = $_POST['enginedata'];
    }

    if(empty($_POST['loc']) || !isset($_POST['loc'])) {
      $data_missing[] = 'Plats';
    } else {
      $loc = $_POST['loc'];
    }
  }
```

Comment: Okay. Here is my result. I even changed the name of the input field to "type".

Array ( [airline] => Test [registration] => t [msn] => 39 [type] => a94 [enginedata] => 2 x 459 [loc] => Test [submit] => Send to server )

Comment: @SamuelAndersson updated my answer